# How do I disable EncryptedLocalStore in Windows 7?

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

I am developing an Adobe Air desktop application which uses Air's EncryptedLocalStore.

[Live docs for Adobes ELS](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/EncryptedLocalStore.html)

I would like to be able to disable this capability on my Windows 7 machine so that I can observe the behavior of the application when this functionality is NOT supported.

Is this possible?
If so, how?